# Boost signal in interface

Tags: c++, qt, boost, interface, signals

I am making the backend model for a Qt application and in the interest of portability (should I decide to scrap Qt) I am using boost as the library behind the model instead of Qt.

Qt has an awesome plugin system which requires using interfaces to communicate between the plugin and the main application. Because of this (and so that parts of the model can be changed out seamlessly) I have defined my model in terms of interface classes that implement all pure virtual functions. Although I haven't declared them as interfaces using the Qt macro (QT_DECLARE_INTERFACE), I don't see a problem using them inside of a "wrapper" interface declared to Qt which would be the face of future plugins.

**Segue to my question**: I read somewhere that a class is considered an interface in C++ if 1) it has all pure virtual members except a virtual destructor and 2) there are no member variables. To me this seems to be purely convention since the compiler doesn't care if it is an "interface" class. It seemed to me after some trial and error with Qt plugins and interfaces that an interface to a plugin only needed to make sure that everything referenced by it had some common code base (i.e. no using classes other than ones backed by a shared library unless the class is also an interface) so that there wouldn't be any unresolved functions. I'm not sure if I am explaining this well, so if further clarification is needed I can give it.

**My question is this** Since a boost signal looks to me just to be a templated member variable backed by a shared library (the plugins would also reference boost), can I use boost signals in classes destined to be used in an interface to a Qt-compatible plugin?

*Code example*

I know this class would probably be ok to be referenced by a Qt plugin interface:

```
class IBlock
{
public:
    virtual ~IBlock() {}

    virtual int getId() = 0;
    virtual std::string getGroup() = 0;
    virtual std::string getName() = 0;
    //etc...
};
```

But is this one also ok?

```
#include "iblockinput.h" //just another interface I made. relationship is: block has many inputs
#include <boost/smart_ptr.hpp>
#include <boost/signals2.hpp> //signals2 is both thread safe and doesn't make the Qt moc angry

class IBlock
{
public:
    virtual ~IBlock() {}

    virtual int getId() = 0;
    virtual std::string getGroup() = 0;
    virtual std::string getName() = 0;
    //etc...

    boost::signals2::signal<void (boost::weak_ptr<IBlockInput>)> sigInputAdded; //there are 4 of these
};
```

It would be awfully handy if it were ok since although Qt doesn't allow placing Qt signals into interfaces (the moc will populate it with code that becomes unresolved eventually) it allows them to be referenced by string names. Boost doesn't allow this whole string reference thing as far as I know, so being able to reference a signal as a normal variable would really clean things up when attaching slots to interface objects.

Comment: qt isn't portable? since when?? btw, the short response to your question is yes.

Comment: I don't mean portable as in cross platform (Qt pwns at cross platform), I meant portable to different GUI frameworks. For example, if I were to switch to GTK+ I would prefer not to have to keep Qt as a dependency as well.

Comment: AFIK moc , the qt metacompiler, generates the code behind the signals and slots, and linking them all up. It was some time ago, but i remember seeing what went into what moc generated, and i can attest it was not pretty. As for the question of wither or not boost signals would work across fameworks, I would say it's possible to make it happen, Though the effort that would go into that would be more than it's worth.